# Why is Product Bounded?

Tags: haskell, bounded-types

http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids :

> `Product` is defined like this:
>
> ```
> newtype Product a =  Product { getProduct :: a }  
>     deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show, Bounded)
> ```

Why is `Product` forced to be `Bounded`?

From the same book, a few paragraphs below:

> Its instance for `Monoid` goes a little something like this:
>
> ```
> instance Num a => Monoid (Product a) where  
>     mempty = Product 1  
>     Product x `mappend` Product y = Product (x * y)
> ```

Eh? The only constraint is `Num a`! But `Num` in particular means `Integer`, and this is not bounded (unlike `Int`), AFAIK.

Let's test it then:

```
import Data.Monoid

numbers :: [Integer]
numbers = [1..100]

main = print (getProduct . mconcat . map Product $ numbers)
```

Let's see this code in action:

```
m@m-X555LJ:~$ runhaskell wtf.hs
93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000
m@m-X555LJ:~$
```

Works. Doesn't fail.

So what's the bound of `Product`? Is there any bound of `Product`?

Let's play again:

```
m@m-X555LJ:~$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> minBound :: Int
-9223372036854775808
Prelude> maxBound :: Int
9223372036854775807
Prelude> import Data.Monoid
Prelude Data.Monoid> maxBound :: (Product Integer)

<interactive>:4:1: error:
    • No instance for (Bounded Integer)
        arising from a use of ‘maxBound’
    • In the expression: maxBound :: Product Integer
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = maxBound :: Product Integer
Prelude Data.Monoid> maxBound :: Product

<interactive>:5:13: error:
    • Expecting one more argument to ‘Product’
      Expected a type, but ‘Product’ has kind ‘* -> *’
    • In an expression type signature: Product
      In the expression: maxBound :: Product
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = maxBound :: Product
Prelude Data.Monoid> maxBound :: (Product Int)
Product {getProduct = 9223372036854775807}
Prelude Data.Monoid> 
Leaving GHCi.
m@m-X555LJ:~$
```

It doesn't seem that `Product` is, by itself, `Bounded`. `Int` is; but `maxBound :: (Product Integer)` throws! IIUC `Product deriving Bounded` is a promise that `maxBound` is well-defined on `Product`. Apparently, not always.

So why is `Product` an instance of `Bounded`?

Comment: `deriving Bounded` doesn't mean that `Product a` automatially becomes `Bounded` for all `a`, it just means it does *if `a` is*

Comment: @RobinZigmond Ah. Didn't know this. Thank you.

Comment: There's nothing special about `Bounded` here fwiw. You're deriving `Eq` as well, but nothing stops you making a type `Product (Int -> String)` for example, which it makes no sense to compare for equality (since you can't do that with functions). Again, the derived instance only exists if the base type `a` is already an instance. Deriving instances does no "magic", it's just an automated way to "do the obvious thing" and save you some boilerplate.

Answer (score 7):

`Product` is not an instance of `Bounded` (that would be a kind error, anyway). You're missing what `deriving` actually does.

There is [a formal specification of derived instances](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch11.html#x18-18200011) in the Haskell report:

> If *T* is an algebraic datatype declared by:
>
> `data cx => T u1 … uk = K1 t11 … t1k1 | ⋅⋅⋅ | Kn tn1 … tnkn
>                      deriving (C1, …, Cm)`
>
> (where *m ≥ 0* and the parentheses may be omitted if *m = 1*) then a derived instance declaration is possible for a class *C* if these conditions hold:
>
> 1. *C* is one of `Eq`, `Ord`, `Enum`, `Bounded`, `Show`, or `Read`.
> 2. There is a context *cx′* such that *cx′  ⇒  C t<sub>ij</sub>* holds for each of the constituent types *t<sub>ij</sub>*.
>
> [...]
>
> Each derived instance declaration will have the form: `instance (cx, cx′) => Ci (T u1 … uk) where { d }` [...]

This means class constraints are automatically distributed to type parameters.

As explained in [the section on `Bounded`](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch11.html#x18-18500011.3):

> The `Bounded` class introduces the class methods `minBound` and `maxBound`, which define the minimal and maximal elements of the type. For an enumeration, the first and last constructors listed in the `data` declaration are the bounds. For a type with a single constructor, the constructor is applied to the bounds for the constituent types. For example, the following datatype:
>
> ```
> data  Pair a b = Pair a b deriving Bounded
> ```
>
> would generate the following `Bounded` instance:
>
> ```
> instance (Bounded a,Bounded b) => Bounded (Pair a b) where  
>   minBound = Pair minBound minBound  
>   maxBound = Pair maxBound maxBound
> ```

For `Product`, this means `Product a` is only an instance of `Bounded` if `a` is.